# How to expect that the '=' method runs for the 'session'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the `rspec-rails 2`gem. I would like to test if some `session` data has been set to `nil`.

In my controller I have:

```
def create
  ...
  session[:user] = nil
  ...
end
```

In the related spec file I would like to make something like the following:

```
it "should be set to nil" do
  # Here I would like to expect if the 'session[:user]' is set to 'nil'
  # NOT using this approach:
  #
  #   session[:user].should be_nil
  #
  # That is, I would be sure that the 'session[:user] = nil' runs the same way
  # I may do with method "expectation". For example:
  #
  #   mock_model(User).should_receive(:find).and_return(nil)
  #
  # Maybe a solution can be similar to this (note: of course, the following
  # doesn't work):
  #
  #   session[:user].should_receive(:"=").and_return(nil)

  post :create, { ... }, { ... }

  ...
end
```

**Is it possible? If so, how?**

*P.S.*: I would like to use that approach in order to check some particular internal behavior.

---

**UPDATE** ... and how can I test the following?

```
session[:user][:nested_key] = nil
```

Answer (score 3):

The method your are looking for is `[]=`:

```
session.should_receive(:[]=).with(:user, nil)
```

This feels really invasive to me, however. Not that I'd never do it, but I'd question why you don't want to just test the outcome?

```
session[:user] = 37
post :create # ...
session[:user].should be_nil
```

Comment: And what if I have to test something like the following? `session[:user][:nested_key]`. P.S.: You said: "[...] why you don't want to just test the outcome?" It is for security reasons.

Comment: OT: Hi David, big fan of your RSpec book, just saying 'hi'!

Comment: You could do something like letting `:[]` return a mock object. Or use `stub_chain`. But as @david says, I would recommend checking only the outcome, because normally it should not matter how it is set to `nil`.